# Image preview in Android webview before upload not working

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-webview

well I m making an android webview app, Im facing an issue here.
I m trying to preview my image on webpage before uploading
Here is my `html and java script` code i m using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var preview = $(".upload-preview img");

    $(".file").change(function(event){
       var input = $(event.currentTarget);
       var file = input[0].files[0];
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.onload = function(e){
           image_base64 = e.target.result;
           preview.attr("src", image_base64);
       };
       reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
});

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="upload-preview">
    <img />
</div>
<input class="file" name="logo" type="file">

</body>
</html>
```

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kulgar/57F67/)

Its working just fine on almost every browser (i.e Firefox, Chrome and IE) without any error or warning. here is snapshot of firefox (showing the preview before upload)
[image]

**Now whenever I try to open this in android webview its not showing the image preview** 
it shows something like this

[image]

I don't know whats wrong, I have enable the `javascript` and included the `jquery`. Its driving me crazy since one day.

here is my android webview code.

```
package net.kaosfield.wv1;

import my.functions.MyFunctions;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Activity activity = MainActivity.this;

private WebView webView = null;

private ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMessage;

private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

private static String registrationId = "";

private MyFunctions myFunctions;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (uploadMessage == null)
            return;
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                : intent.getData();
        uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        uploadMessage = null;
    }
}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myFunctions = new MyFunctions(activity);

            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setInitialScale(myFunctions.setWebViewScale());

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("net.kaosfield.wv1:")) {
                Log.d("wv1", url);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d("wv1", "onPageFinished");
            String argument = "d.e.f";
            view.loadUrl("javascript:alert(window.method(\"" + argument
                    + "\"))");
        }
    });
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,
                JsResult result) {
            if (message.equals("net.kaosfield.wv1")) {
                try {
                    Log.d("wv1", "url: " + url + ", message: " + message);
                    return true;
                } finally {
                    result.confirm(); // in order not to alert
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // For Android 3.0+
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            uploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),
                    FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        // For Android 3.0+
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                String acceptType) {
            uploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                    FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        // For Android 4.1
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                String acceptType, String capture) {
            uploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),
                    MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }
    });

     webView.loadUrl("http://blue.genetechz.com/qadir/test.php");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up
    // to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

}
```

Comment: In which android version did you test? FileReader isn't supported by android < 3.0

Comment: @jcesar Yes I got this error while testing on android 2.3.3 AVD. but in 4.0 + it not giving any error but the problem remains the same.

Comment: I've just tested your code and worked on a 4.1.1 device

Comment: really?  Sorry I had tested it on 4.0.4, its not working.

Comment: BTW, I tested the HTML code on an existing phonegap project, so in case you have anything wrong in the code it must be on the java part.

Comment: What should I do now? should I move to phonegap. I haven't enough experience. what should I do.?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41080/discussion-between-qadir-hussain-and-jcesar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make this changes on the onActivityRestult because the urls returned from the gallery aren't right:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

        if (uploadMessage == null)
            return;

        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                : intent.getData();
        if (result!=null){

            String filePath = null;

            if ("content".equals(result.getScheme())) {

                Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(result, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();   
                    filePath = cursor.getString(0);
                    cursor.close();

            } else {

                filePath = result.getPath();

            }

            Uri myUri = Uri.parse(filePath);
            uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(myUri);

        } else {

            uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);

        }

        uploadMessage = null;
    }
}
```

Now it will return an url with the `file:///` format even if you choose the image from the gallery.

Comment: Thankkkkkkksssssssssssssssssssssssss is not enough for you :) live long

Comment: Hey I tried your solution but it only shows the image name but not the image.Please help me.

Comment: Can you give more info?

Comment: @jcesar:I have the same requirement like the above question so I used the code from above and changed the `onActivityRestult ` code as per this answer.But I am only getting the image name.

Comment: If you have the same it works, so if it doesn't work you don't have the same. In which device are you testing? android version?

Comment: @jcesar I tested in nexus 7 and 2.2 emulator too.

Comment: @jcesar: I just changed the ` webView.loadUrl()` line .Instead of the url I passed the html file path which is inside the asset folder.Is that causing a problem ?

Comment: @jcesar: I have posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/q/21040284/1665507.

Comment: @jcesar Your code gave me solution but that solution is working only on Devices it is not working on Tablets. Can you please provide me solution that will work on tablets too ?