# Image preview in Android WebView only shows the image name

Tags: android, webview

I have a very small requirement.I want to show a image in the `WebView` from gallery.But after browsing from gallery, it only renders the image name instead of showing the image.I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19947559/1665507) post. Below are html and java script code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var preview = $(".upload-preview img");

    $(".file").change(function(event){
       var input = $(event.currentTarget);
       var file = input[0].files[0];
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.onload = function(e){
           image_base64 = e.target.result;
           preview.attr("src", image_base64);
       };
       reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
});

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="upload-preview">
    <img />
</div>
<input class="file" name="logo" type="file">

</body>
</html>
```

and below is the Android code,

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        Activity activity = MainActivity.this;

        private WebView webView = null;

        private ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMessage;

        private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

        private static String registrationId = "";


 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

        if (uploadMessage == null)
            return;

        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                : intent.getData();
        if (result!=null){

            String filePath = null;

            if ("content".equals(result.getScheme())) {

                Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(result, new String[] {    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();   
                    filePath = cursor.getString(0);
                    cursor.close();

            } else {

                filePath = result.getPath();

            }

            Uri myUri = Uri.parse(filePath);
            uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(myUri);

        } else {

            uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);

        }

        uploadMessage = null;
    }
}

        @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Web);

            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (url.startsWith("net.kaosfield.wv1:")) {
                        Log.d("wv1", url);
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    Log.d("wv1", "onPageFinished");
                    String argument = "d.e.f";
                    view.loadUrl("javascript:alert(window.method(\"" + argument
                            + "\"))");
                }
            });
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,
                        JsResult result) {
                    if (message.equals("net.kaosfield.wv1")) {
                        try {
                            Log.d("wv1", "url: " + url + ", message: " + message);
                            return true;
                        } finally {
                            result.confirm(); // in order not to alert
                        }
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                // For Android 3.0+
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                    uploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("image/*");
                    MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),
                            FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                }

                // For Android 3.0+
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                        String acceptType) {
                    uploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("image/*");
                    MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                            FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                }

                // For Android 4.1
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                        String acceptType, String capture) {
                    uploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("image/*");
                    MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),
                            MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                }
            });

            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/abc.html");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
            // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up
            // to the default
            // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }

    }
```

but after picking a image from gallery, it only shows the image name.Below is the screen shot. Could anyone tell me whats wrong here?Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: what do you get if you alert(file);? and System.out.println(filePath); on the activityResult?

Comment: @jcesar: `/mnt/sdcard/276273_100000078519719_1666366274_n.jpg`. This is the path I am getting

Comment: on both? that is a good url, it should work

Comment: @jcesar: Sorry I couldn't get what do you mean by ` alert(file);`

Comment: It doesn't matter, alert(file); won't work, it alerts [Object File] or something like that. I have no clue about your problem, the url is right

Comment: @jcesar: is there any jquery file required to be added in the asset folder ?

Comment: No, you are loading it from the CDN and the other things are working

Comment: Do you have this permissions on the manifest?  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44946/discussion-between-spring-breaker-and-jcesar)